# How can I use more colors for dots on a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import numpy
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

violet=[0.872,0.947,1.016,1.075,1.120]
transmission=[20.0,40.0,60.0,80.0,100.0]

fit_violet=numpy.polyfit(transmission,violet,1)
fitpol_violet=numpy.poly1d(fit_violet)
xfit=numpy.linspace(0.0,120.0)
yfit_violet=fitpol_violet(xfit)

pl.plot(xfit, yfit_violet, 'k', linewidth=2, label=u'Rectas de ajuste')
pl.plot(transmission, violet, 'bo', markersize=6, label=u'Valores experimentales')
pl.xlim(0.0,120.0)
pl.show()
```

As far as I know, I can only choose the basic colors for the dots in the plot, using the letters 'b' for blue, 'r' for red, and so on. But I would like to be able to choose a specific shade of violet for these dots. Is it possible to use a wider range of colors for this type of plot?

Comment: From the [matplotlib colors api](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/colors_api.html) you can also use RGBA values, or hex values as in `color = '#eeefff'`

Comment: @G.Anderson But how should the syntax be? I have tried that but it gives me an error (non-keyword arg after keyword arg).

Comment: Tha toccurs when you mix keyword (`linewidth=2`) and positional (`xfit, yfit_violet`) args.One way to avoid that error in the future: Use keywords for all args to make it unambiguous: `pl.plot(x=xfit, y=yfit_violet, c='k', linewidth=2, label=u'Rectas de ajuste')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `color` argument you can supply any color in a variety of different formats.
Those are listed in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_demo.html).

> Matplotlib gives you 8 ways to specify colors,
>
> 1. an RGB or RGBA tuple of float values in [0, 1] (e.g. (0.1, 0.2, 0.5) or (0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3)). RGBA is short for Red, Green, Blue, Alpha;
> 2. a hex RGB or RGBA string (e.g., '#0F0F0F' or '#0F0F0F0F');
> 3. a string representation of a float value in [0, 1] inclusive for gray level (e.g., '0.5');
> 4. a single letter string, i.e. one of {'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w'};
> 5. a X11/CSS4 ("html") color name, e.g. "blue";
> 6. a name from the xkcd color survey, prefixed with 'xkcd:' (e.g., 'xkcd:sky blue');
> 7. a "Cn" color spec, i.e. 'C' followed by a single digit, which is an index into the default property cycle (matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']); the indexing occurs at artist creation time and defaults to black if the cycle does not include color.
> 8. one of {'tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown', 'tab:pink', 'tab:gray', 'tab:olive', 'tab:cyan'} which are the Tableau Colors from the 'tab10' categorical palette (which is the default color cycle);

In your question you are referring to number 4 of this list. Instead consider e.g.

```
plt.plot(x,y, color="violet", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x,y, color="#ee82ee", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x,y, color=(.9333, .5098, .9333), linewidth=2)
```

all leading to the same violet color.

Comment: Oh wow. My mistake was that I was writing the 'o'  after the "violet", instead of the other way around, which produced the "non-keyword arg after keyword arg" error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You will use something like this:

```
pl.plot(transmission, violet, "o", color="#EE82EE", markersize=6, label=u'Valores experimentales')
```

Giving:

[image]